# URL alias in view with subfolder of the Drupal installation

Tags: views, path-aliases

I've never seen this before:

This D7 installation runs in a subfolder of my dev server. The same way as all the other installations.

In a view I have a field with the node alias path. But this path I get with the subfolder.

Drupal runs in: myserver/subfolder/mydrupal
The path is: this-is-my-node

I should get: this-is-my-node

I get: /subfolder/this-is-my-node

When I overwrite the output of this field with [path] all works fine.

What could be happened?

Comment: Have you uncommented RewriteBase / in .htaccess?

Comment: works. but I never had this before...

Thank you!

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your root .htaccess file and uncomment `RewriteBase /`

This should set the new root for your Drupal installation when operating out of a sub folder. This is usually required when enabling Clean URL's.